# How to disable startup applet warning dialog?

Tags: java, dialog, applet

I have SELF-signed applet. Is it possible to see only next message from Java (which happens only once)

[image: Desired prompt]

NOT THIS (which happens everytime when I load applet)

[image: Dont want to see this]

Maybe adding something to java.policy or java.security ? Or disable this in Java Console. If somebody familiar with this, kindly help me :)

If you are not familiar with this messages, read this please: 
[What should I do when I see a security prompt from Java?](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/appsecuritydialogs.xml)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Maybe adding something to java.policy or java.security ?

On the machine of every user of the applet?  That has never been practical.

> Or disable this in Java Console.

You mean introduce what amounts to weak security in the interface Oracle offers to configure their plug-in?  No.

> If somebody familiar with this, kindly help me :)

Oracle, (as well as me for that matter) are more interested in helping the end user to *avoid* applets like this one which is self signed.  If the user saw only the 2nd prompt as seen above, for an unverified applet, it would be nothing short of a security bug in the JRE.  If you find a way to achieve, please report it to Oracle so they can have that bug fixed quickly.

Comment: Did this aggresive warning dialog for self-signed code was added 1.7.0_51 update ? My app is for small amount of users, thats why I asking.

Comment: *"1.7.0_51 update ?"*  The changes started around 1.7.0_45, but that doesn't really matter since.. *"My app is for small amount of users, thats why I asking."* ..those 'small amount of users' should have an up to date, secure JRE.  If an applet tries to load itself in an earlier JRE, you risk messages like *"This applet is requesting and old and **insecure** version of Java.  Do you want to continue?"*

Comment: While I fully understand the reason to have those warning dialogs, in reality, the end users couldn't care less. End users will see the dialog to update Java (and they often don't have admin rights to do so and must choose update later), then they see the dialog displaying the certificate of the signed JAR (and the always trust this certificate checkbox went right over the end users' heads), then perhaps one more dialog for the applet having to interact with JavaScript. You will end up with end users complaining about the dialogs. They won't learn why, they won't learn how.

Answer (score -1):

Seems the certificate used to sign the applet jar expired ..please sign it with valid self signed certificate ..

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have added my site to exception site list (so I dont have this yellow part (like on second screenshot). Yep, this yellow msg included when your certificate is expired, you dont have some attributes in manifest, etc (https://www.java.com/en/download/help/trusted_expired_variations.xml).